# MIRC Port Scanner

Tags: python, sockets, irc

```
  if data.find('!scan') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     targetip = str(socket.gethostbyname(args))
     sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" ' scanning host' + " " + targetip + '\r\n')
     for i in range(20, 1025):
         s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         result = s.connect_ex((targetip, i))
         if (result == 0) :
              s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'port %d: OPEN' % (i,) + '\r\n')
         s.close()
```

The script works, but it ping timeout before it can get an open port, how can I make it so it can scan a few ports then check for a ping from the server and send a pong then scan a few more ports so that it wont ping timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use multiple threads, with the main thread parsing input from IRC and responding to PINGs, while other threads do actual command processing and anything that could take a long time.

[skybot](https://github.com/rmmh/skybot/), my IRC bot, spawns a new thread whenever a command is issued, and uses thread-safe queues to pass messages between them.

Comment: A thread-safe queue is a good idea for a bot. I should add that to my plugin-based bot.